# Confirmation box with okay cancel C# web application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have a custom control list view with check boxes. If user check one list item, code will flow as it is. If user check more than one check boxes, it will show a alert message "Scheduled more than one time slots for the same day will overwrite the file" with Ok and Cancel.

If user click okay he will allow and go with functionality. if he click cancel, it should return back and uncheck the second value he checked.

I have tried in lot of different ways by using Javascript. None of it worked out. Please Help.

And I can not use OnclientClick/OnClick because i am using the same list view to bind different datasource. I need to pop up the alert message only when a listview with schedule time values with multiple checks. Please find **if condition** in the below C# code.

**Code-Behind:**

```
 protected void chkCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox chkCheck = (CheckBox)sender;
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)chkCheck.NamingContainer;
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)item;
        if (lookupMstVal == "ScheduledTime." && lbCheckedIdList.Items.Count > 0 && chkCheck.Checked)
        {
            //To do
        }
          string lookupId = lvLookup.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
            if (chkCheck.Checked)
                lbCheckedIdList.Items.Add(lookupId);
            else
                lbCheckedIdList.Items.Remove(lookupId);
            hdfLookupId.Value = "";
            foreach (ListItem itm in lbCheckedIdList.Items)
            {
                hdfLookupId.Value += (hdfLookupId.Value == "" ? "" : ",") + itm.Value;
            }
            postbackFlag = true;
     }
```

**.axcs**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvLookup" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
                ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvLookup_PagePropertiesChanging" DataKeyNames="DCLookup_Id">
                <LayoutTemplate>

                    <table style="width: 100%">

                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <%-- <th id="colLookupId">Lookup Id</th>--%>

                            <th>Lookup Values
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTimeZone" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="ui-helper-center">
                                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvLookup" PageSize="10">
                                    <Fields>
                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                            FirstPageText="<span style='font-size:16px;'><b><<</b></span>" PreviousPageText="<span style='font-size:14px;'><b><</b></span>" ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"
                                            ShowPreviousPageButton="false" LastPageText="<span style='font-size:16px;'><b>>></b></span>" NextPageText="<span style='font-size:14px;'><b>></b></span>" />
                                    </Fields>
                                </asp:DataPager>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </tr>
                </GroupTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ClientIDMode="AutoID" ID="chkCheck" ToolTip='<%# Eval("DCLookup_Id") %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkCheck_CheckedChanged"/>
                    </td>
                    <%--<td id="colDCLookupId">
                    <%# Eval("DCLookup_Id") %>
                </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("DCLookup_Value") %>
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No Records
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

It might easy for someone but for me i have been spending from 2 days.

Please Help!  Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation). It has confirm/cancel options.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean value say "blnNeedpopup" and set it to true only when you need the pop-up.

And while binding the datasource to listview in .DataBound method you can add ONCLICK to the checkBox element only if the blnNeedpopup is TRUE. So that yo will get those pop-ups only as per your conditions.

Also when user clicks OK or Cancel you don't need to do a post back instead can handle in simple JQuery function.